# How to calculate cross-correlation in xarray in python?

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

I am using xarray trying to calculate the cross-correlation between 2 different time series. One is the JJA NINO index, one is the precipitation value. So I would like to make the correlation beween NINO index and Precipitation, I would like to see the correlation with no lag ,and precpitaiton lag for 3 months,6 month, 9 month, and 12 month. How can I achieve it? The time series are both 2D.

Comment: Hello - welcome to stack overflow! Please see this guide on [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask). Specifically, we need more detailed information about what you're working with and where you're stuck. StackOverflow users aren't just here to write your code for you, but if you point out what you've tried, ideally with a [minimal reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) we're here to help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.